# Why min-width: 35em and not 480px or 30em?

Tags: html5boilerplate, breakpoints, css

In the latest version of h5bp, you are using min-width:35em for the first breaking point in your queries. I was curious as to why this number specifically? Is this based on the latest smartphone screen sizes or something? Typically its usually been 480px/30em for the first break point.

Comment: Who do you mean by "you guys"? :)

Comment: Couldn't you have just asked them?

Comment: @Pekka I think he meant "youse guys".

Comment: @cimmanon, Pekka: There's a link to Stack Overflow in the bottom of their home page. I guess this misleads people into thinking SO is run by the same people who work on H5BP, and is their official support channel or something.

Comment: @BoltClock but the question isn't about how to use their tools, it's about why they chose to design something the way they did.  It would be something only the designers themselves could answer.

Comment: @cimmanon: Exactly. The OP probably thinks SO is H5BP's official feedback or support site (which it isn't).

Comment: A note on the off topic closing; this question is *clearly* aimed at the group maintaining HTML 5 Boilerplate.  That said, if the question was reworked to take that out and make it a *constructive* question about why those pixel widths were chosen, then it would be a good fit for Stack Overflow.